# Angularjs: Cannot find module "../../node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have installed bootstrap and when I run the application using webpack I am facing this error:

> Angularjs: Cannot find module “../../node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot”

Webpack.config.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');  
    module.exports = {      
      entry: [     
        './app/app.js',     
        './app/index.html',     
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',    
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081/'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',      
        path: __dirname + './js'
    },
    module: {  
        loaders: [  
            // Exports Angular  
            { test: /[\/]angular\.js$/, loader: "exports?angular" },  
            // Script Loaders  
            { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee" }, 
            { test: /\.html/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' },  
            // Style Loaders, style! inlines the css into the bundle files  
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css!less" },  
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass" },  
            { 
                test: /\.less$/, 
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(  
                    // activate source maps via loader query   
                    'css?sourceMap!' +  
                    'less?sourceMap'  
                ) 
            },  
            { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, loader: "file-loader?me=images/[hash].  [ext]"},  
            { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },  
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,               loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },  
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },  
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    loader: "file" },  
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,    loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }  
        ]},
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '',  
            '.js', '.coffee',  
            '.html',  
            '.css', '.styl', '.scss', '.less'  
    ]},  
    plugins: [  
        // extract inline css into separate 'styles.css'   
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')  
    ]};
```

Comment: Did you install bootstrap using npm? I mean by running a command like `npm install --save bootstrap`

Comment: yes I have installed bootstrap